# How to make a chart with an associative array with chart.js?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have an app in PHP using Laravel and I've got two arrays I have to join in a single chart. Both show a quantity per month. I could write a single label as the documentation shows for a normal use case but both lines don't necessarily include the same amount of months so I'd like to associate each y axis figure to its specific month label.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('flujomes');
var entregas = @json($ar_entregas);
var reversas = @json($ar_reversas);
console.log(entregas);
console.log(reversas);
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            label: "Número de entregas",
            data: entregas,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        },
        {
            label: "Número de reversas",
            data: reversas,
            backgroundColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)'
            ],
            borderColor: [
                'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)'
            ],
            borderWidth: 1
        }
    ]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true
                }
            }]
        },
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
    }
});
```

However it doesn't work as I expected:

[image: The way datasets are displayed]

[image: Chart displayed.]

So chart.js picks up the data but it doesn't know where x points actually are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the library doesn't know who to handle the `x` values that you are giving, only if you are using a linear axis (numerical data) it will be able to do this correctly without other options.

There are two ways to solve this,

---

### Option 1 - Define a `category` axis

Since you know the values that will be on the labels you can set them with the `type: 'category'` , so library knows where to put the points correctly like the following example:

```js
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    datasets: [{
      label: "Data 1",
      data: [{
        x: '2018-2',
        y: 98
      }, {
        x: '2018-4',
        y: 74
      }, {
        x: '2018-5',
        y: 52
      }],
    }, {
      label: "Data 2",
      data: [{
        x: '2018-3',
        y: 25
      }, {
        x: '2018-5',
        y: 52
      }],
    }]
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'category',
        labels: ['2018-2', '2018-3', '2018-4', '2018-5']
      }]
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'x',
      callbacks: {
        title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
          let tI = tooltipItems[0];
          return data.datasets[tI.datasetIndex].data[tI.index].x;
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="ctx"></canvas>
```

### Option 2 - Transform the labels into dates

Another possible solution will be to transform the labels from text into `Date()` with moment like `moment("2018-2")` and then set a `min` and `max` as `ticks` value, and also the display format, with something like:

```
xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
        displayFormats: {
            quarter: 'YYYY-MM'
        }
    }
}]
```

This is in overall a more complex solution.

---

### Update - fix, wrong tooltip title

As mention the first solution will lead to when a user hover a point the title of the tooltip will be different from the `x` label, that is because that point carries a wrong `index` value (this `index` is used to return the label position).

In attempting to solve this, and since the `Scatter` charts create a similar result with what we are trying to achieve, I have locked up at the controller of this type [here](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/d6a5ea0d3629f8687ccd12637f221bd3c68451d1/src/controllers/controller.scatter.js), but without luck, because in this situations or the title is ignored or the value is also wrong.

So what I came up with is something like this:

```
tooltips: {
  mode: 'x', // optional
  callbacks: {
    title: function(tooltipItems, data) {
      let tI = tooltipItems[0];
      return data.datasets[tI.datasetIndex].data[tI.index].x;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically instead of searching the index in the labels array, it will get the original `x` data value.

Comment: Thanks, the first solution is enough to show the chart correctly, except for one thing: https://i.imgur.com/bjRFRcO.png It's weird because according to the console, the x value for that y is correct (2018-4) but the tooltip label shows 2018-3.

Comment: @ffuentes I have added a snippet of code that will fix this, please check out the example code, and let me know if it works.